# Why is this temporary table sticking around between connections?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm running the following:

```
logging.error('TYPEOF: %s', type(self.db_engine))
logging.error('CREATE 1')
with self.db_engine.connect() as connection:
    table_sql_create = CreateTable(MyTmpModel.__table__)
    connection.execute(table_sql_create)
logging.error('CREATE 2')
with self.db_engine.connect() as connection:
    table_sql_create = CreateTable(MyTmpModel.__table__)
    connection.execute(table_sql_create)
logging.error('SUCCESS')
```

I see the `TYPEOF` log statement (it logs `TYPEOF: <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>`) and the `CREATE 1` and `CREATE 2`; the second create block crashes with `\"Table 'tmp_table' already exists\")`

The model has,

```
__table_args__ = {'prefixes': ['TEMPORARY']}
```

on it. The connection is closed and re-opened; the table should have been destroyed with it, no?

According to [the SQL Alchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.close), `close`, which is called via the `with`'s `__exit__`,

> results in a release of the underlying database resources, that is, the DBAPI connection referenced internally. The DBAPI connection is typically restored back to the connection-holding `Pool` referenced by the `Engine`

How do I really actually close the connection?

Comment: Use [`Connection.invalidate()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.invalidate).